# Pass Boolean Values from Ajax to PHP

Tags: php, json, ajax, mailchimp

I've read a tonne of questions on the subject but none of them seam to solve my particular issue – I guess there's something wrong with the way I've formatted my array of objects in JS. Here's my Ajax function:

```
var marketing_prefs = [];

$('#save-marketing-prefs input').each(function() {
  var tmp_array = {};
  tmp_array['marketing_permission_id'] = $(this).val();

  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    tmp_array['enabled'] = 1;
  } else {
    tmp_array['enabled'] = 0;
  }

  marketing_prefs.push(tmp_array);
})

console.log(marketing_prefs);

$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
  data: {
    action: 'acrew_save_mc_marketing_prefs',
    marketing_prefs: marketing_prefs
  },
  success: function(response) {
    console.log('#####', response);
  },
  error: function(response) {
    console.error('!!!!!', response);
  }
});
```

What I'm doing is looping through a simple form with three checkboxes and creating an array of objects which will then go off to Mailchimp. My data arrives intact but the problem is that my boolean values come over to PHP as strings. I've switched from using true and false which was coming over as "true" and "false", to using 1 an 0 but those come over as strings too.

I suppose I could loop through the data and build a new array in PHP but the data is so close to being correct when it arrives that it seems like it must be unnecessary.

How can I get my data over as non-strings?

Comment: GET/POST data doesn't have any way of specifying datatypes, everything is a string.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmer. Yeah, I picked that up on my travels but also that passing 1 and 0 might better/easier to interpret as bool at the receiving end.

Comment: @KevinNugent  _Why_ are you wanting this exactly?

Answer (score 1):

`POST` data is sent as simple `name=value` pairs, there's no syntax to specify datatypes, and everything is parsed as strings.

You can call `intval($_POST['marketing_prefs'][$i]['enabled'])` to convert it to an integer.

Another option is to convert the `marketing_prefs` array to JSON.

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
  data: {
    action: 'acrew_save_mc_marketing_prefs',
    marketing_prefs: JSON.stringify(marketing_prefs)
  },
  success: function(response) {
    console.log('#####', response);
  },
  error: function(response) {
    console.error('!!!!!', response);
  }
});
```

Then in the PHP you can do:

```
$marketing_prefs = json_decode($_POST['marketing_prefs'], true);
```

Comment: So when I stringify my data it comes out looking like this: `[{\"marketing_permission_id\":\"4af4cbc99a\",\"enabled\":1},{\"marketing_permission_id\":\"61800c79a5\",\"enabled\":1},{\"marketing_permission_id\":\"09a72e340f\",\"enabled\":1}]`

Comment: That's why you need to call `json_decode()` in PHP.

Comment: And when I `intval` it just returns 0.

Comment: You would only see escaped backslashes if you're stringifying twice.

Comment: How are you seeing that result?

Comment: So when I stringify outside of my Ajax function and log the output I get what I assume to be the 'correct' format: `[{"marketing_permission_id":"4af4cbc99a","enabled":1},{"marketing_permission_id":"61800c79a5","enabled":1},{"marketing_permission_id":"09a72e340f","enabled":1}]`. But once that's passed to PHP it's formatted with all the backslashes. So something is double-strigifying it along the way.

Comment: How are you printing it when you see the backslashes?

Comment: `$new_prefs = $_POST['marketing_prefs'];`
`error_log( "\n\n" . date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . "\n" . $new_prefs, 3, plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . "tmp/my-errors.log" );`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204370/discussion-between-barmar-and-kevin-nugent).

Answer (score -2):

Since, as Barmar stated, GET/POST can't specify data types (that's a rant in and of itself), one way would t be to cast it.

Very rough example:

```
var_dump((bool) <variable>);
```

The issue is if it's anything but 'true', 'empty' or I believe 0 it will return true.  I'm in a hurry else I'd flush it out for you better.

Comment: The issue is the reason I suggested `intval()` instead.

Comment: A really good suggestion so long as you pass numeric values as he is right now.  If you wanted to go back to true/false I think casting is the only option, at least in my limited knowledge.  So long as it's POST and the values are for sure known, cast isn't to awful bad.  I'd personally stick with integers though.